# C# - Create excel workbook event handlers during runtime from array of excel instances

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I have searched the net but cannot seem to find what I need. 
I am creating an application where I detect all the Excel Applications currently running in the system. It is returned through a class by indexers:

```
ExcelAppsInMemory excelAppsInMemory= new ExcelAppsInMemory();
for(int i=0; i<excelAppsInMemory.Count; i++)
{
   excelAppsInMemory[i].WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(frmDirtyExcel_WorkbookOpen);
}
```

Well, you have guessed it right... *it dosen't work*. So, how do I create event handlers for Workbook events for excel applications that are captured during runtime.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926205/does-every-excel-interop-object-need-to-be-released-using-marshal-releasecomob?rq=1

Comment: @kd. the link is for releasing com object reference, my question was regarding creating event handlers during runtime

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @kd. Simply speaking : Create Excel event handlers during runtime, (the count of excel apps is not fixed and is only known during runtime).